# pyttsx3 save_to_file() fails to work on macOS

Tags: text-to-speech, pyttsx3, pyttsx, espeak

pyttsx3 fails to work on my mac (python 11)

```
# sample code from the readme

import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.save_to_file('Hello World', 'test.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Actually, pyttsx3 fails to work on mac and I found this issue [Not working pyttsx3 on macos](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/297) mentioned https://pypi.org/project/py3-tts/ and with `py3-tts` it can work on my mac.

But `save_to_file` fails to work, the code just stucks there and won't exit. After some trial and error I found that I can save tts to a wav file NOT mp3. But why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because NSSS (the default MacOS speech engine) doesn't support exporting to `.mp3`.

I tried to install **espeak-ng**, the latest fork to original **espeak**, (check https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng?tab=readme-ov-file#history) to see if espeak-ng can be supported. But sadly it fails to run on macOS. So I have to save tts to `.wav` file and use other tool convert it to `.mp3`